# Gcc: Similar option as mstructure-size-option for x86 32 bit

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, arm

Im porting some generated code from Keil to Linux. This C code is automatically generated by a GUI PLC tool and shall not be changed(is the controll logic, which is created by the end user for his use case)
This did only run on ARM Hardware with Keil OS.
Now we want to run this software on ARM and x86 32 bit

For ARM we have the option `-mstructure-size-option=32` to make structs at least 4 bytes. This option is not available for x86 and the code does not run without this option because of e.g.

```
struct myStruct { char i; }
```

- On ARM Linux `sizeof(myStruct)` = 4 bytes with `-mstructure-size-option=32`
- On x86 32 bit Linux `sizeof(myStruct)` = 1 byte

Is there an option for gcc to make struct sizes multiples of 4 bytes on x86? I'm not talking about padding or alignment inside the struct...

Comment: but **why** do you need that? What's wrong with `char _padding___[3]` there

Comment: Is this what you want? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277196/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277196/how-to-tell-gcc-to-set-structure-size-boundary-to-4-bytes-through-compiler-setti)

Comment: @sebastian it doesn't work on my x86 compiler. It is an ARM option.

Comment: From reading the documentation I'd say **no** since if there *were* it would probably be named that `-mstructure-size-boundary` but it doesn't work on x86-32, 64 or any other GCC version.

Comment: If the structure must of size 4, you will have manually add the padding.  The `-mxxxx` options to GCC are machine-specific, rather than completely generic.  You'll need to know whether the Keil compiler puts the implicit padding at the start (unlikely) or end (probable) or somewhere else (improbable) in the structure it creates with the option in effect.  Or revise the code so that this is no longer an issue.  I can't think how/why you make it so that your code depends on the 4-byte size, but there must be ways or you'd not be asking about it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the C code is generated by a PLC GUI tool, I must not change the code manually... a possible option would be to generate a post processing step for the code via e.g. python script which adds padding to structs manually, though a huge hack...

Comment: Is it 'minimum size is 4' or 'size must be a multiple of 4 bytes'?  Can you use a `union` with an `int32_t` element to force the size to a multiple of 4?  The information about 'C code generated by a PLC GUI tool' should probably be in the question.  It isn't going to make life any easier, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the example struct mentioned above is embedded in other structs... all structs have to be int x=sizeof(struct) and x%4=0 because of the business logic of this PLC software

Comment: The good news is that if the structure contains an `int` (or larger), `float` or `double` type, its size will be a multiple of 4 unless you're perverse enough to use packing pragmas.  So, only structures that contain only `char` or `short` fields/arrays will not automatically have a size that's a multiple of 4 bytes.  For those structures, you'll probably have to add the padding manually.  I still find it surprising that the code doesn't work unless the structure sizes are all a multiple of 4 bytes; it's never something that's been an issue for me in my 30+ years of C programming.

Comment: I should have listed 'pointer types' as forcing sizes that will be a multiple of 4 bytes too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: an option instead of explicit padding is `struct foo{ _Alignas(4) char i; };`, forcing the compiler to create implicit padding so the size is a multiple of the alignment.  https://godbolt.org/z/vgwofb.  But you have to apply that to a member, not to the outside of the struct itself.  Oh, but gcc does allow `struct __attribute__((aligned(4))) small{ char i; };` with the desired effect.  (Not exactly identical to a 4-byte struct with `alignas(1)`, though, if embedded into another struct.)

Comment: `aligned(4)` could result in padding in an outer struct, before the inner struct, if it has a `char` or `short` member.